# Apt debug-symbols package empty

Tags: apt, gcc, debugging

I am trying to install debug symbols for `gcc`. Searching around I have:

```
gcc-4.7-dbgsym/xenial,now 4.7.4-3ubuntu12 amd64 [installed]
debug symbols for package gcc-4.7

gcc-4.7-multilib-dbgsym/xenial,now 4.7.4-3ubuntu12 amd64 [installed]
debug symbols for package gcc-4.7-multilib
```

`gdb` does not find the debug symbols when I load `gcc-4.7` into the debugger. So I checked to see which files these packages had installed:

```
$>  dpkg-query -L gcc-4.7-multilib-dbgsym 
/.
$>  dpkg-query -L gcc-4.7-dbgsym 
/.
```

It seems these packages are empty? Am I doing something wrong? Or how can I check if the debug symbols are actually installed.

Checking under `/usr/lib/debug` I didn't find anything.

Comment: Where did you get the package `gcc-4.7-dbgsym`? It doesn't seem to be in the standard Ubuntu repos

Comment: Hmm, I thought it came from the standard repo. I can see it listed [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-4.7).  Otherwise I followed this [guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages) for getting debug symbols.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting the GCC source directly from apt:

```
apt get source gcc
```

This installs the gcc source into a local directory. From here, I compiled GCC with debug flags and no optimizations. The compilation takes a very long time, so you might consider loading the `gcc` binary through `gdb` and merely pointing to the source [like this](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html), basically using the `dir` command. This may lead to some unexpected behavior as GCC will still have optimizations on.